Fried USB-C hub: what was my mistake?
Yesterday I was using for the first time this USB-C hub with a Dell laptop. A monitor and my charger were connected to the hub, which was connected to the thunderbolt port of my laptop.

It worked great for 5 minutes, then I heard a click sound from the hub and my charger and the monitor went off. The thunderbolt port, the charger and the monitor still work, but the hub is apparently dead.
I saw later that the hub was rated for 87 W, and my charger can deliver up to 130 W. I am no electronician, but normally this is not a problem right? The hub is limiting my laptop to pull more than 87 W from the charger. What have I done wrong?

The hub may have lied about it's capabilites. Take it apart! See what is broken.

There's lots of junk technology related to USB specifically. Had the same thing happen with an USB port expansion card, some short between Vdd and chassis caused components to go poof. The key here is to never buy electronics from garbage vendors.

And even if you buy from reputable vendors, it's a good idea to be critical.

Your only mistake was trusting that you got a usable product. Buy from a reputable source and Amazon, sadly enough, isn't one unless you know exactly what to look for - and even then you may get scammed. Unfortunately, Amazon seems to let fraudulent product descriptions stand. And some more apropos that.
That HUB is junk. Return it for a full refund. If the seller makes it hard, dispute the transaction with your bank/credit card provider. Any card with a Visa, Mastercard, Discover, or American Express logo should allow disputes - it doesn't matter if it is debit or not.
